# How to prevent YouTube from from resizing videos to fit screen (in full screen mode)?

Tags: youtube, video

First, please take a look at [**this video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zicjQyzXSiw) in full screen mode.

Although it's pretty clear, what I am doing there, in the video, I feel it would be much crispier (at least I like it that way) and clear if it could look in its actual size like [**it does here**](http://www.screenr.com/0K4s) (again, please see in full screen mode).

Is there a way to make that happen in YouTube too? I've seen a couple of videos like that before, but can't find any now.

---

If you don't understand what I am referring to, then take a look at how YouTube videos look in full screen mode here:

[image: YouTube Full Screen]

Then see how I want it to look like here:

[image: After]

Note that I am the one that uploads the videos to YouTube, and the videos should appear as aforementioned, to all YouTube users, with the changes you suggest me to make.

Is there at all a way to do what I intend to do?

Comment: Both linked sources are unavailable. The question depends on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've learnt finally, there's no way to do it. But that's really unfortunate.

---

**EDIT:** Although not what I really hoped for, [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) actually allows you to view YouTube videos in their original resolution.

1. Open VLC
2. Go to **Media** (menu) → **Open Network Stream...** → paste the YouTube video URL in field under the label **Please enter a network URL:** and hit **Play**.
3. When the video has loaded, play the video, right-click on the video, under **Video** (menu item) → select **Fullscreen** option; then right-click again, and under the same menu item (i.e. **Video**) deselect **Always Fit Window** option.
4. The video should now be playing in its original resolution.